# Pyramid of char Array

Tags: c#

Index is out of Range when the pyramid is on last element of an array
I've tried to change a position of an increment element i and j but problem is the same. I must to use while loop.

This is the Code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Write word");

string s = Console.ReadLine();

char[] charArr = s.ToCharArray();

int i = 0, j;

while (charArr[i] != 0) {
  j = 0;

  while (j < i) {
    Console.Write(charArr[j]);
    j++;
  }

  Console.WriteLine();
  i++;
}
```

Comment: You use *wrong technique*: `charArr[i] != 0` will work in **c**, but not in **c#**; in c# string *doesn't end* by `\0`. Instead you can check `while (i < charArr.Length) {...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the *wrong approach*: unlike **C** `string` in **C#** doesn't end by `\0`.
That's why condition within `while` will ever be `true`:

```
while (charArr[i] != 0) { // ever be true 
  ...
  i++; // i increases until i will be out of [0..charArr.Length - 1]
```

As a quick amendment you can put

```
while (i <= charArr.Length) {
```

However, I suggest using `for` instead of `while`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Write word");

string s = Console.ReadLine();

for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
    Console.Write(s[j]);

  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wN6oeU)